# C# TcpClient "The operation is not allowed on non-connected sockets."

Tags: c#, tcpclient

My goal is to create a TcpClient that *stays connected*, allowing messages to be sent to the server, as well as having a timed monitor that sends a special message to the server during a certain idle frequency.  Haven't made it too far before getting stumped.

With the current code, the first message sent using a console tester app receives fine, but upon sending another an exception is thrown with the message "The operation is not allowed on non-connected sockets."

I have tried removing the stream.Dispose() line and it will hang on stream.Read(...) during the second attempt.  I have also tried making NetworkStream stream a member of the class and set it to client.GetStream() in the constructor and it will hang on stream.Read(...) during the second attempt.

```
public class TcpClientTest
{
    private TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
    private string hostName;
    private int port;

    public TcpClientTest(string hostName, int port)
    {
        this.hostName = hostName;
        this.port = port;
        client.Connect(hostName, port);
    }


    public byte[] SendMessage(string name, string message)
    {
        if (client == null) throw new Exception("Client connection has not been established");

        Person person = new Person();
        person.Name = name; person.Message = message;

        byte[] messageBytes = (System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(person)));
        const int bytesize = 1024 * 1024;
        try 
        {
            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

            if (stream != null)
            {
                stream.Write(messageBytes, 0, messageBytes.Length); // Write the bytes  

                messageBytes = new byte[bytesize]; // Clear the message   

                // Receive the stream of bytes  
                stream.Read(messageBytes, 0, messageBytes.Length);
            }


            // Clean up  
            stream.Flush();
            stream.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);

        }

        return messageBytes; // Return response  
    }
}

// In console tester app
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TcpClientTest client = new TcpClientTest("127.0.0.1", 1234);

        string exit = "2";
        do
        {
            if (exit == "1") client.SendMessage("TEST", "TEST");              
            Console.WriteLine("1 Send Message 2 Exit");
            exit = Console.ReadLine();
        } while (exit != "2");


    }
```

Comment: for sure dont do dispose on that stream. Apart from that it is impossible to diagnose wihtout seeing more code. YOu say this code works the first time you call it but not the second, what do you do between those 2  operations

Comment: When you dispose the stream it closes the connection. You should either move your tcpclient connection to that function as well, or dispose the tcpclient only  when finished

Comment: just a note, you can NOT reliably do `stream.Read(messageBytes, 0, messageBytes.Length);`, just because you asked for `messageBytes.Length` bytes does not mean you will get `messageBytes.Length` filled in, also one `Send(` by the sender can be broken in to multiple `Read(` by the receiver (in fact two sends can be joined in to a single read too). You ***MUST*** use some kind of [message framing](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/message-framing.html) and repeatedly call `Read` until you have the full message you are looking for.

Comment: I have added an edit to include what is going on between calls to SendMessage... as you can see not much.